# How to use array.map with a 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I need to loop through an array, but the statement is located between brackets [ ]

It is however not allowed to place a for-statement between brackets and will therefore result in an `SyntaxError: missing 'of' after for`

searching the internet, I found out that array.map() could be a solution.
I could however not find a example of an array.map on a multidimensional array, and can't get my code to work.

The example below creates a table and exports it into a pdf file.
This works correctly, but works only for a static table:

```
var docDefinition = {
content: [
{
  table: {
    body: [
      [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
      [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
      [ 'Val 1', 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
    ]
  }
}
]};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lya7uds/)

I need the code to work for a dynamic table.
I'm trying to create a table from an array, can't get it to work properly.
This is what I have so far:

```
function html2Pdf(){
var arr = [[ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],[ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],[ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]];    
var docDefinition = {
content: [
{
  table: {
    body: [
     arr.map(function(item){
        return item
     })    
    ]
  }
}
]
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lya7uds/2/)

Comment: Why don't you just have `body: arr`?

Comment: Also click the `<>` and post the code here instead of JSFiddle in a [mcve]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As commented before it's pretty okay to inject the given array into resulting structure directly.

```
table: {
    body: arr
  }
```

Regarding your question on how to use array map on two-dimensional arrays: you can nest it quite as you would do with for-loops or similar.

```
body: arr.map( function( row ) {
    return row.map( function( cell ) { 
        return foo( cell ); 
    } );
} )
```

Comment: Injecting the array into the structure directly did work. Thank you for also explaining the use of array.map on a multidimensional array.